# Hello, LEGO. I have one question

Tags: design, lego-group

LEGO group, thanks, to read this
My question: 
       How get work in LEGO?
What i have to do now, to get work in future?
I'm 13 years old.
My MOC(i have too many good works, but i can send only one image):
[GV-NT-X 478 USC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc77n.jpg)
                            P.S. I'm bad in English, but i learning        this language.

Comment: This site is not run by The Lego Group, it's just people who like Lego.

Comment: Welcome to LEGO Answers, and nice MOC! We've closed this question as it is a duplicate of another. Hopefully the answers on that question are helpful to you.